# Update Series Array on HighChart after editing chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an areaspline HighChart, where I have it implemented in a way that I can drag series points up and down on the Y-Axis and return the new of the point. I followed this example http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/. The series of points is create from the following array `data = [6,4,13,6,21,22]`

In my code there is the following function:

```
 drop: function() {
 $('#drop').html(
 this.series.name + '</b> to</b> was set to <b>' + 
 Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>'
 ),
}
```

This is the function that updates the point I choose to move with the new value after I stop dragging the point.

However I am struggling to get my head around one or two things. 
First of all, say for example I move the point 4 in the array, and I increase the value to 8. When I log the array after I move this point the new array is returned with the x co-ordinate as well as the new value for that point, so for example the returned array is now `data = [6,1(or this.x value),8(new this.y value), 6,21,22]`. Or if I log the `series.data`, it returns:

```
 series.data = [object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object]
```

I am presuming the reason it returns the x co-ordinate value is so that the graph can correctly get the new position of the point you choose to move.

How do I just return the the array with the updated this.y value? So in the example above the returned array will be `data = [6,8,13,6,21,22]` or just return the value `Object` to the array?

Secondly, when I log the array output after I finish editing, it logs the output twice. Is there any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It may be a roundabout way of doing it, but it works.

So looking into the issue more, the new value of a point after I update is returned as an array `[Xpos, Ypos]`. So in the example above, `data = [6,8,13,6,21,22]` is the array I begin with and the returned new array: `data = [6,8,13,[Xpos,Ypos],21,22]`.

So to remove the Xpos value in the new returned array I had to go through the array after it is updated, and for each element in that array, check if it was an instance of an array. If it was an instance of an array, I set that element equal to the Ypos element. This return the new value for the point on its own.

So where this was done was in the drop function in this example:

```
     function drop(e) {
        if (dragPoint) {
            if (e) {
                var deltaX = dragX,// - e.pageX,
                    deltaY = dragY - e.pageY,
                    newPlotX = dragPlotX - deltaX, //dragPoint.series.xAxis.minPixelPadding,
                    newPlotY = chart.plotHeight - dragPlotY + deltaY,
                    series = dragPoint.series,
                    newX = dragX === undefined ? dragPoint.x : dragPoint.series.xAxis.translate(newPlotX, true),
                    newY = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.y : dragPoint.series.yAxis.translate(newPlotY, true);

                newX = filterRange(newX, series, 'X');
                newY = filterRange(newY, series, 'Y');
                dragPoint.update([newX, newY]);
            }   

         //My code to remove the newX from after the dragPoint.update([newX, newY]);             
         for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(data[i] instanceof Array)
                        {
                            data[i] = data[i][1];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data[i] = data[i];
                        }                            
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All yData you can find in: `series.yData` and example: [jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/AyUbx/724/)